# Approaches for document classifications?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

I am trying to classify a bunch of documents. So far I have tried several approaches:

- Machine learning based approach: such as KNN, Decision tree, SVM, etc.
- Rule based: try to extract some rules from the training corpus for each category.
- Keywords based: try to extract keywords from training corpus to represent each category.

Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of macro-approaches there is still one missed: hybrid. You can try to merge machine learning-based and rule-based. The literature is full of papers about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Natural language processing approach.

More here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing